# using Quaternion for IMU data

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, accelerometer, quaternions, gyroscope

I have an IMU device 6 DOF(3 DOF accelerometer and 3 DOF gyroscope). I want to use it to rotate an object in unity3d. For that I calculate the Euler angles roll, pitch and yaw.

My problem is the singularity of the pitch angle at +90degrees and -90degrees. I need to solve it.

I read that using quaternions instead of euler angles this problem disappears.
I am very unexpert of Quaternion, and how can I use Quaternion with data getting from IMU sensors? How can I use it to rotate a gameobject in unity3d?
Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify the data you get out of the IMU?

Comment: What I suspect is that you will want to use the Quaternion multiplication operator. You will start with your initial Transformation, `t1`, and build an new Quartonian `q1`, using the instantaneous data from the IMU. Then update the transformation using `t1.rotation * q1` (or possibly in reverse as order matter for multiplication here).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I get  the three angular rates (degrees/s) by gyroscope and the three acceleration components (g) by accelerometer. So I don't know how to use these data to build a quaternion. Do I start with an initial quaterion q1=[1 0 0 0] and then I have to update it as q1 = t1.rotation*q1? Sorry but I don't have any experiences with quaternions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the way to do it. You will probably want to use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html to generate the incremental quaternion and Quaternion.identity to get your initial quarternion.

Comment: Ok but how I can use IMU sensor data to build a quaternion? How I use them? Thank you

Comment: I'm not quite sure on the acceleration components by you could just take the three angular speeds multiply them by a suitable time and feed those into  the Quaternion.euler method.

Comment: I am solving the problem by means this Madgwick filter http://x-io.co.uk/res/doc/madgwick_internal_report.pdf. 
Now I have another quastion, I use in unity3d transform.rotation to rotate a gameobject by Quaternion, but does the rotation rotate also the unity axis?

Comment: I'm not really a unity expert, but in most systems, you can apply transformations to most things. So you can rotate the world, the camera or an individual object.